# Stripping Whitespace PHP

Tags: php, regex, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a Problem with RegEx and PHP, I have this string:

```
Panorama - SPIEGEL ONLINE - Nachrichten                                                                                                                                                Schlagzeilen                        Hilfe                        RSS                        Newsletter                        Mobil                        Wetter                        TV-Programm                                                            Dienstag, 26. Februar 2013                                    Panorama                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    NACHRICHTEN                                                                Home                                                                    Politik Deutschland                                                Ausland                                                &nbsp;                                                                                                                                                WirtschaftB
```

I would like to strip all spaces, which are not needed, so all spaces but one, so that the words are still seperated by one space.

I wrote this regex:

```
echo trim(preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $lol));
```

And I'm very close:

```
Panorama - SPIEGEL ONLINE - Nachrichten Schlagzeilen Hilfe RSS Newsletter Mobil Wetter TV-Programm Dienstag, 26. Februar 2013 Panorama NACHRICHTEN Home Politik Deutschland Ausland   WirtschaftB
```

What am I missing? Thank you very much!

Comment: Your code is basically right, you just used the wrong kind of quotes. Inside double quotes, you need to escape the backslash, `\\s`.

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for the duplicate! And thanks for the downvote -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `&nbsp;`. This is a non-breakable space in your browser. Use this:

```
$string = "Panorama - SPIEGEL ONLINE - Nachrichten                                                                                                                                                Schlagzeilen                        Hilfe                        RSS                        Newsletter                        Mobil                        Wetter                        TV-Programm                                                            Dienstag, 26. Februar 2013                                    Panorama                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    NACHRICHTEN                                                                Home                                                                    Politik Deutschland                                                Ausland                                                &nbsp;                                                                                                                                                WirtschaftB";
$string = str_replace("&nbsp;"," ",$string);

echo preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $string);
```

demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c85dcc5ba0c9aa9306125ad5878c02d07fcf452